# Categorical product of non-unital associative differential graded coalgebras

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, graded-algebras, differential-graded-algebras

Given two non-unital associative dg coalgebras $D$ and $C$, I want to give an explicit construction of the product $C\prod D$, this may follow from the dual construction (coproduct of non-unital associative dg algebras). I have read the article [*A closed model structure for differential graded algebras*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/JardineModelDG.pdf) by Jardine and found that given two **unital** associative dg algebras $A,B$, we have:
$$A\coprod B=T(A\otimes B)/I$$
where $I$ is the ideal generated by elements of the form $(a_1\otimes b_1)\otimes (1\otimes b_2)-(a_1\otimes b_1b_2)$ and $(a_1\otimes 1)\otimes (a_2\otimes b_2)-(a_1a_2\otimes b_2)$.

How could I reformulate this quotient when both $A$ and $B$ have no units?.

In the case of coalgebras, I would appreciate a few hints to make the dual construction. Thanks.